# Django Oauth Toolkit Application Settings

Tags: django, oauth, django-rest-framework

Django Oauth Toolkit docs don't describe the redirect uris, authorization grant type, or client type fields when registering your application.

The tutorial says to set client type to confidential, grant type to password, and leave uris blank.

What do the other options do?

e.g. What is client type public vs confidential?  What do the grant type password, credentials, authorization, implicit do?  And what are the redirect uris for?

I have found sparse information about them but no actual explanations as they pertain to django rest framework and django oauth toolkit.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You'll get answer to all your questions once you read about Oauth2 Protocol from [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)

But I'll try to answer your questions in brief:

I'll be using the words `client` and `Resource Server` frequently. In `Oauth2` protocol, `client` means the system which accesses resources, data or service. (It could be your mobile app or javascript app consuming REST API's of your API Backend (or `Resource Server`) . If you have implemented Facebook login in your mobile/JS apps, chances are, your API backend requests Facebook for user's information. In that case your API backend is being a `client` and Facebook is `Resource Server`)

**Client Types:**

Client type is either `confidential` or `public` depending on whether that client can keep it's `client_secret` a secret. (For example, an `AngularJS` app cannot keep it's `client_secret` hidden, since anyone can do "Inspect Element" in a browser and search for it, so such a `client` has to be registered as `public`.)

**Authorization Grant Types:**

There are four kinds of `Authorization Grant Types` in `Oauth2` protocol.

1. **Authorization Code:**

   In this grant type, the `client` requests for an `authorization code` first, then exchanges that `authorization code` for an `access token`. It's a two step procedure. Use this if the `client` is an *outsider* (more on it in `Resource-owner password based`).
2. **Implicit:**

   Usually used along with `public` `client_type`. Instead of a two-step procedure above, the `client` gets `access token` in one go.
3. **Resource-owner password based:**

   This is used when there is a *high degree of trust* between `client` and `Resource Server`. This is the case between your API backend and your Mobile app. (There is high degree of trust between your API backend and `Javascript` app too, but since it cannot keep it's `client_secret` a secret, you have to use `Implicit` Grant type with it). `Facebook` or `Google` etc. will never give you this kind of `Authorization Grant` because, for them, your API backend is an *outsider*.
4. **Client Credentials:**

   It is least commonly used. Please read about it in above mentioned document.

**Redirect URI's:**

Now, as far as `Redirect URI's` are concerned, they are needed only in `Authorization Code` or `Implicit` grant types (Not sure about `Client Credentials` one, somebody please enlighten me on this in comments).
Redirect URI is given so that the `Resource Server` knows where to send the `access token`. Imagine if you are implementing Facebook login. In that case you will go to `developers.facebook.com` and register your application (like you did with `django-oauth-toolkit`), while registering your application, you will specify a `Redirect URI`.

Specifying a `Redirect URI` is a way of saying. "Hey Facebook, send the access token on this URI". So if you set `Redirect URI` something like https://your_domain_name.com/token/facebook/, `Facebook` will redirect to your specified `Redirect URI` at the end of Oauth2 process and give `Access Token` in the form of `GET` parameter, like https://your_domain_name.com/token/facebook/?token=some_long_string&some=other_parameters.

Comment: One question I have is about the redirect uri's. In the OAuth2 Protocol RFC, for implicit and authorization grant types it has the client specify the redirect uri in the request optionally.  How is this different than the redirect uri you set up when registering the application?

Comment: Not 100 % sure about that, but I think this is the answer:

when registering an application one can specify multiple redirect uri's

so when client specifies the redirect_uri in request, it has to specify one of the redirect_uri's that were specified during application registration.

It's just for client's convenience. Personally, I have not encountered a situation where this multiple redirect_uri thing is beneficial