# Using Django's OAuth2.0 Authentication with Android Utilizing Volley

Tags: android, python, django, oauth-2.0, android-volley

I am creating an Android app that will be using a Django backend, along with the Django Rest Framework. I have been reading the OAuth2 documentation, but am still struggling to understand a few key points about its authentication.

These are my main questions/things I'm struggling with:

- In OAuth2, I am given the oppurtunity to create 'apps'. Would the 'app' in this case be specific to my Android app (and presumably in the future I would create a different one for a potential iOS app?).
- Will all users of the (Android) app be using the same token, or is each user granted an individualized token?
- I am using the Volley library for Android to deal with networking. How do I go about getting the Android app to 'store' the needed credentials? Would I be storing the token, id, and secret, or just the token?

If it is worth noting, I do not plan on adding social media logins (Facebook, Google, etc) I will just have login be with a username and password.

I'm sorry if these questions seem a bit elementary, this is my first experience will authentication of any sort.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll be using the word "app" to mean two different things:

1. `app`, to indicate Oauth2 app, which you'll create to register your mobile app(s)
2. app, to indicate mobile app.

**Answer 1:**

An `app` is basically a way of registering a `client` (in this case, your mobile app) with the `resource server` (in this case, you `Django` backend). You can go either ways, creating two separate `apps` or a single `app` for your Android and iOS apps. Unless you are not planning to give users of one app some more privileges or features, I don't see benefit in creating two separate `apps`.

**Answer 2:**

Each user is granted a different `access token`.

**Answer 3:**

You'll have to store `client_id` and `client_secret` in some secure way on your mobile app(s). Because that's what will help you gain an `access token` for a user, in first place. You'll also store `access token` after obtaining it, because it will be needed in making authenticated HTTP requests.

For more information on Oauth2 Protocol in general, you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37548045/django-oauth-toolkit-application-settings/37694559#37694559) answer, and Oauth2 Protocol [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749).

Comment: Okay thank you so much! One more question just to clarify, **client_id** and **client_secret** will be the same for every phone/app install, but **access token** will be different for every user?

Comment: yes, that's what I wrote above, access token will be different for every user