# Register an application automatically in Django OAuth Toolkit

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is there any way to register an Application Automatically in Django OAuth Toolkit?

I have watched how register an user in
[Django OAuth Toolkit - Register a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49031954/django-oauth-toolkit-register-a-user)
and Application settings [Django Oauth Toolkit Application Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37548045/django-oauth-toolkit-application-settings)

However, I did not find the way to create an Application when a User is registered, and create the Client ID and Client Secret automatically.

In the documentation I only found it:

https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rest-framework/getting_started.html#step-3-register-an-application in Step3.

Comment: Why do you want to create Client ID and client secret automatically? They are not used on a per-user basis

Comment: I have a Wordpress plugin and Prestashop module. They get info from Django Rest Framework. I would like a Secret ID and Client ID for as client that download the plugin and register for use it, not only a Secret ID and Client ID for plugin.